# Where to start when developing an app for a website

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wordpress, web

I am planning on developing an iPhone App for a website, powered by Wordpress.

Where can/should I start codewise when developing an app for such sites?

Should I use Wordpress' API, or should I access the (MySQL) database directly?

I am very open for ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd beg you to consider just why a blog needs it's own *application*. Specially when it'd be viewable just fine on the iPhone as, you know, a website.

Comment: @silky: Because someone asked me to. Maybe they want an easier interface, etc. I don't know :p

Comment: One option would be to set up a plugin and use that as an interface between the app and your site.

Comment: @incrediman A plugin for Wordpress, you mean? I am not that good at PHP and such. Interface between.. - what do you mean?

Comment: I am going to keep this question unanswered for a while, until I get to test all answers. I will then accept the answer I will use in the finished project. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to set up a plugin and use that as an interface between the app and your site.

Comment: A plugin for Wordpress, you mean? I am not that good at PHP and such. Interface between.. - what do you mean?

Comment: Yes. As I understand your problem, you want to make your (client's) wordpress site's data/database so you can access it through an app you'll be developing. What I'd suggest is to create a plugin for wordpress that will expose an interface through which you can communicate with your site via POST/GET. More specifically, you'd create a wordpress plugin that would take in POST/GET requests, and output data about your site. In that sense the plugin could act as communication layer between your site and your app. However if you're not great with PHP this probably is not the route to go...

Comment: No, this should actually be a pretty simple script. I might try that too, actually! Thanks :)

Comment: I ended up using this method as it is much easier to get the contents of the post from something *in contact* with the Wordpress system (a plugin). Thank you, @incrediman :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help. That's why I suggested it actually - it can be quite annoying to try interfacing with wordpress sometimes, but I've had the best luck with this in the past.

Answer (score 8):

how about taking a look at the [WordPress Iphone Open Source project](http://iphone.wordpress.org/development/)?

// Jakob

Comment: That's a site for the Wordpress App.

Comment: Yes, and you asked where to start. I guess, since you are using Wordpress, you could start of by looking at the code in the app?